# discord js bot enter a voice channel and play a sound

Tags: discord.js, bots

this is my code that should make the bot enter the voice channel and play a sound:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers]});
var isReady = true;

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('suono')
        .setDescription('fa un suono'),
    async execute(interaction){
        await client.on('ready', message =>{
            if (isReady){
                isReady = false;
                const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guild_id)
                const member = guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id);
                var voiceChannel = member.voice.channel;
                voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{
                    const dispatcher = connection.play('./1.mp3');
                    dispatcher.on("end", end => {voiceChannel.leave();});
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        });
    },
};
```

i tried many time but for now the code compile and work but when i run the command on discord it says:"the application hasn't replied"

Answer (score 1):

You should always send a response when using Slash Commands:

```js
var isReady = true;

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('suono')
        .setDescription('fa un suono'),
    async execute(interaction){
            if (interaction.client.user){
                const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guildId)
                const member = guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id);
                var voiceChannel = member.voice.channel;
                interaction.reply('playing...');
                voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{
                    const dispatcher = connection.play('./1.mp3');
                    dispatcher.on("end", end => {voiceChannel.leave();});
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
    },
};
```

Comment: maybe it' s something i should know, but i get a error because it can t read the properties of undentified ('members')

Comment: can you retry with my updated code?

Comment: now can read member but, Cannot read properties of null (reading 'join')

Comment: this is because you are executing the command without being connected to a voice channel?

Comment: i am connected to the voice channel, on the discord chat the bot is actually replying with the text 'playing...' but on the log on vscode i get this error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'join')' and it don t enter the voice channel

Comment: You should make sure you have the VoiceStateUpdate intent enabled

Comment: How can i make sure i have it enabled?

Comment: When using discord.client() pass the right intents there. A simple search "python voice intent discord" should do the trick.

Comment: I think I found it and now I know what it is but i can t find what intent should i use, i tried `GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates` but i doesn't work, am I using the wrong intent?

Comment: you should use: new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates,Discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds] })

Comment: I did this `const { SlashCommandBuilder, Client, GatewayIntentBits,IntentsBitField, Discord } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,Discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates, Discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds]});` am I doing it wrong?

Comment: const { SlashCommandBuilder, Client, GatewayIntentBits,IntentsBitField, Discord } = require('discord.js'); const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.IntentsBitField.GuildMembers,Discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates, Discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds]}); (Androz#2091 on Discord)

Comment: now it can't read the property of Client (Tsurao#0309 on discord)